# How to register a domain name in Italy?

Tags: domain-name, dns-hosting, domain-registration

Is there a DNS registry/hosting service as convenient as Dreamhost or Network Solutions for ***.it*** domains?

Answer (score 2):

[Gandi.net](http://gandi.net/) can register it for you, and I've got nothing but good things to say about them.

Answer (score 0):

I have used www.marcaria.com. Good service.